# Is there any way to run PowerShell snippet in Package Manager Console as a VS 2022 'macro'?

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, keyboard-shortcuts, package-manager-console

**Context**

I have many PowerShell snippets, what I am using in VS 2022 PM> console, for example something like this:

```
#... some lines here
$dte.ExecuteCommand("Tools.ImportandExportSettings", '/export:'+$filenameEscaped)
#... some lines here
```

Currently I use this a pretty inconvenient, and productivity killer way:

- I look for the text file which contains the code lines either in file system, either in the project (in case it contains it)
- copy the lines to the clipboard
- open the PM> window
- paste the code on the clipboard.

**Question**

The productive way would be, just pressing a keyboard shortcut... Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: You have to start VS As Admin.  Right Click VS shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Comment: I do not have problem with running the script, this question is not about that.